# Add Custom Audience to Ad Group Targeting

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

I would like to add an existing custom audience to an ad group using the API.

The problem is that it looks like I can only update the entire targeting field at once and the targeting field includes connections which I do not have permission to change.

In other words, the solution I have right now is

1. Read the current targeting field
2. Add the custom audiences
3. Remove the connections
4. Update the targeting field

If I don't do step 3, I get a permission error. This is not acceptable since I only want to add a custom audience without changing anything else. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't believe there is a way to do this as you cannot update a adcreative, but instead you have to recreate it. As you can see in the documentation, you only have the ability to chance an adcreative's name:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/adcreative/#update

If you do not have permission, you will not be able to achieve this.